# Version Control Branching

Tags: version-control, tfs

I'm using TFS version control and am very new to version control in general. The project I'm working on needs a new feature added. Would I branch the entire project or would I only branch those individual files or folders as I work on them? It seems easier to just copy the solution folder and work on an entire new copy but then if I have to go back and fix bugs in the original version I'll have to do them again in the new version. I'm a bit nervous because I've never used branching before and I don't want to screw my project up.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to branch at all?

Comment: Then I will be able to fix bugs on the current version of the web app while working on the features of the next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's personal preference but check out the Rangers Guide to branching here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/17/alm-rangers-ship-the-new-branching-and-merging-guide-v2-1.aspx

for your situation, i would branch the whole solution, it makes it easier to develop if you have the whole solution, when you are happy you can then merge in your 'feature' branch back to the original branch. If changes have occured on the original branch in the mean time you may have to manualy merge files during the merge operation.

Comment: Branch parts of solution it's not a good pattern, because when you test the software you don't test just a file, but the entire software